# How can I read files from usb device on android?

Tags: android, usb, usb-otg

I'm trying to create something like file explorer through connected usb devices(via OTG or usb ports on android TV). 
All I need for this is a path something like "/storage/sda4" and device identifier, and then I can work with device through simle android class File. Is sounds simple but I can't find any info about this, but all file explorers can do it (for example ESExplorer).
Ok, I find a simple way to get all connected usb devices with identifier

```
UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
usbManager.getDeviceList();
```

but how can I get an info about path? deviceName contains something like this "/dev/bus/usb/00x" but it can't help me, I need simple emulated android path ("/storage/sda4"). This page https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html tells that I need to get UsbInterfaces and make UsbConnection to bulk transfer and other bullshit, I done it all but didn't find path to device or any other info about usb file list.

Ok, I find another way to get (that don't requires permission!) to get path to all connected devices

```
StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
Method getVolumeListMethod = StorageManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("getVolumeList");
Object[] storageVolumeList = (Object[]) getVolumeListMethod.invoke(storageManager);
```

and it works but I need to identify a device(because I want to cache files of different usb storages) but all that I can get from volume object is mStorageId, mDescriptionId, mPrimary, mRemovable, mEmulated, mMtpReserveSpace, mAllowMassStorage, mMaxFileSize, mOwner, mUuid, mUserLabel, mState, mSubSystem.
None of this can not identify the device: mDescriptionId and mStorageId are
unique fot usb port, mUuid is null, mUserLabel is not unique.

Environment.getExternalFilesDirs() won't help, it don't provide any device id and works only with one device.

I find a similar question here, but it has no right answer [Android list files from USB Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795622/android-list-files-from-usb-drive).

Well, is a simple way to get list of usb devices with path and identifier exists?

Comment: Have a look at `getExternalFilesDirs()`. The third entry would be the otg usb drive.

Comment: I'm just edited the question, I mentioned getExternalStorageDirectory instead of getExternalFilesDirs. It don't provide any device identifier

Comment: For what do you need a device id if you want to make a file explorer? You only need a path. And getExternalFilesDirs() will give you that. Dont tell that it does not!

Comment: And it gives you a different path for a different usb drive. And the drive id is in the path like /ADAE-12FE/.

Comment: @greenapps I want to cache devices that was inserted, and if you insert same device second time I want to show user info about filesystem tree.

Comment: Well go ahead. What's the problem?

Comment: @greenapps the problem is . the file path keeps changin with every usb insertion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> All I need for this is a path something like "/storage/sda4" and device identifier, and then I can work with device through simle android class File

No, because [you do not have arbitrary access to removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), including USB OTG drives, on Android 4.4+.

> all file explorers can do it (for example ESExplorer)

Pre-installed "file explorer" apps may have additional rights granted to them by the device manufacturer or custom ROM developer. Otherwise, they too do not have arbitrary access to removable storage.

> is a simple way to get list of usb devices with path and identifier exists?

Not with a filesystem path, no. `getStorageVolumes()` on `StorageManager` will give you a list of storage volumes, which includes external storage and removable storage. You can then use `createAccessIntent()` on `StorageVolume` to ask the user for permission to work with the volume. If they grant permission, you get a `Uri` back that:

- Serves as a temporary identifier for the volume (i.e., will no longer be usable as an identifier if the user ejects the media, but until then, can distinguish one volume from another), and
- Lets you work with a portion of the contents of that volume, though using `Uri` values, not filesystem paths

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer. I try getStorageVolumes, but it requires 24 API and higher, but for now it spreads out not so much. After your answer I understand that only way I can do it is the second second way that I described, it provide me the path of all devices, and I can work with simple class File(I tested it on android 5 and 5.1:) Maybe it is defect of android but it truth. I will use mUserLabel as an id, that unique in most cases.

Comment: StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
Method getVolumeListMethod = StorageManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("getVolumeList");
Object[] storageVolumeList = (Object[]) getVolumeListMethod.invoke(storageManager);   I use these lines to get list of storage volumes but I get only /storage/emulated/0 , while my OTG was connected with a pendrive. Why I am not getting path for OTG connected  device?

Comment: @Anupriya: Possibly because you are using reflection to get at something that is not supported on the version of Android that you are running.

Comment: @Anupriya are you make it for every object? I tested it on android 4.4.+ and it works everywhere:              Field pathField = object.getClass().getDeclaredField("mPath");
        pathField.setAccessible(true);
        Object pathObject = pathField.get(object);

Comment: @Vladislav I have tried everything but its not giving the expected result, maybe the manufacturer hasn't provided the permissions to access removable media.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry to bring this up 3 years later. But I am trying to access the storage volumes using `getStorageVolumes()` for a device that has USB OTG capability. But getStorageVolumes() is only returning the internal/shared volume. I am sure the connected usb device (which is an Honor phone) is mounted because the default file explorer app is showing  all the files in the connected phone via MTP. I am on android 8.0/8.1 AOSP & the default file manager app is com.android.documentsui

Comment: @kb_14: Off the cuff, the manufacturer might have gone their own way on handling USB storage. Does this device have an SD card slot? If so, if you put in a card, does it show up in `getStorageVolumes()`?

Comment: This device does not have an SD Card slot unfortunately. Only internal storage and USB OTG capability