# Get /dev device path of attached USB device

Tags: android, xamarin, android-things

I installed Android Things Developer Preview 5.1 (OIR1.170720.017) on my Raspberry Pi.

The app was created using Xamarin against Android 8 Platform API level 26.
I want to detect hotplug events when a USB thumb drive is being attached. I archieved this by using Broadcast-Receiver in my code:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached, UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceDetached })]
public class MyBroadCastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public event EventHandler UsbDeviceAttached;
    public event EventHandler UsbDeviceDetached;

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.Action.Equals(UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceDetached)) UsbDeviceDetached?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        if (intent.Action.Equals(UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached)) UsbDeviceAttached?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
    private MyBroadCastReceiver receiver;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        this.receiver = new MyBroadCastReceiver();
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        RegisterReceiver(this.receiver, new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached));
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        UnregisterReceiver(this.receiver);
        base.OnPause();
    }
```

Now, I have an empty USB thumb drive with no partitions or filesystems on it, just plain block storage. When attaching or detaching the drive, the `OnReceive(Context, Intent)` method is called. I took a look at the `context` and  `intent` arguments, but I was not able to determine more information about the device attached. Many properties more appear to be null:
[image: Content of intent argument]
I want to obtain the /dev node of the device (not /mnt or whatever mount point may be used when the drive has a filesystem on it). Looking in `dmesg` I can see that the block device was assigned to the node `/dev/sda`. Is there any way to get the node name/path from code? Do I need some additional permissions for that? 
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42474815/3290339

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer my question: How do I find out the /dev/ node of the device being attached?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41890251/6950238) question and answers.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. The libaums provides access for non-rooted device to the usb mass storage device and to the fat32 filesystem, if available. 
However, I searched along to find out how to read/write raw data to the block device and how to create new partitions and filesystems. This is pretty simple using the dd command and mkfs. But I am afraid I cannot find a way to do such things programmatically within my app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android's security model prevents apps from accessing raw device resources like the `/dev` node of an attached USB device. You will need to go through the USB APIs to communicate with the device.

You might want to review the [USB Enumerator sample](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-usbenum) for Android Things to get a better idea of how to use the Android USB APIs to detect the device insertion and open a communication channel to the device.

Specifically, USB device attachment is not handled as a broadcast by apps. It's triggered as an activity intent for an app that filters on the given device type. The [USB Host API Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) can also provide you more details on how all this works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the notes.